# I have used a function to generate xls. But the generated xls sheet doesn't have scroll functionality with arrow keys

Tags: excel, attributes, schema, spreadsheet

Hi I have used the following function to generate a excel workbook template which I later use to generate an excel xls file and write it to response(asp.net).

```
private static string getWorkbookTemplate()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(818);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:ss=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" xmlns:html=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@" <Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""Default"" ss:Name=""Normal"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Alignment ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Borders/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <NumberFormat/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Protection/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s62"" ss:Name=""Header"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#FFFFFF""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#5A0B0E""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s63"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <NumberFormat ss:Format=""Short Date""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s64"" ss:Name=""RowArea"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#FFFFFF""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#723B3E""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s65"" ss:Name=""SummarySection"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""0""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);//
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s66"" ss:Name=""TotalRow"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11""{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s67"" ss:Name=""PosValues"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#008000""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    // sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);//
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s68"" ss:Name=""NegValues"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#A31515""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //  sb.AppendFormat(@"    ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);//
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);

    //New Style Defined Ganesh
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s69"" ss:Name=""TotalRowSummarySection"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#000000"" ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //sb.AppendFormat(@"    />{0}", Environment.NewLine);//
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);


    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s70"" ss:Name=""BoldPosValues"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#008000"" ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //sb.AppendFormat(@"    />{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);

    sb.AppendFormat(@"  <Style ss:ID=""s71"" ss:Name=""BoldNegValues"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Font ss:FontName=""Calibri"" x:Family=""Swiss"" ss:Size=""11"" ss:Color=""#A31515"" ss:Bold=""1""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //sb.AppendFormat(@"    />{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"   <Interior ss:Color=""#FFE5E6""  ss:Pattern=""Solid""/>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.AppendFormat(@"  </Style>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    //New Style Ends

    sb.AppendFormat(@" </Styles>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    sb.Append(@"{0}\r\n</Workbook>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I am able to generate the file successfully and also am able to open the file in excel. But when I use the arrow keys to go through cells the sheet remains stagnant. i.e. it wont scroll, and when I use my mouse and press the scroll button on scroll bars it works. The cursor keeps going to new cells whose location I can see besides the formula bar in excel 2007. The page however doesn't scroll. I created another excel file using EPPlus which doesn't have this issue. Can anyone please suggest if it possible to control the scroll in the excel spreadsheet schema.

Comment: The code above is written in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this file actually is stored as spreadsheet ML (xml) file. which is why I am getting this issue. If I save it as 2003 xls then I am able to scroll using the arrow keys. And also I found an answer on stack overflow where it was suggested that in order to achieve this I need to send it to a service which has access to excel and which can generate the required excel file. I tried using WCF for this but it was unacceptably super slow for download. So I used this technique.